# Drawing a ggplot out of a nested list with dataframes

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, purrr

This is my dataframe

```
df <- tibble("Fruit_Name" = c("Banana", "Apple", "Orange", "Peach", "Pear", "Watermelon"), "Code" = c(1,1,2, 2,3, 3), "Share_2002" = c(0.116, 3.442, 2.445, 1.932, 0.985, 0.321), "Share_2010" = c(1.4, 2.8, 2.4, 2.10, 0.99, 1.04), "Share_2018" = c(0.161, 0.232, 1.234, 0.456, 0.089, 0.06), "Share_2018_bis" = c(0.5, 0.34, 1.5, 1.2, 0.75, 1.8))
```

From this initial dataframe I constructed a nested list:

```
    fruits <- df %>%
  rename("2002" = Share_2002,
         "2010" = Share_2010,
         "2018" = Share_2018,
         "2018bis" = Share_2018_bis) %>%
  arrange(Code)%>%
  group_split(Code) %>%
  map(~list(fruit_normal = .x, fruit_long = .x %>%
                            gather(Year, Share, c(3,4,5), -Code, -Fruit_Name) %>%
                            arrange(Fruit_Name) %>%
                            mutate_all(funs(str_replace(., "2018bis", "2018"))),
            fruits2 = .x %>%
              gather(Year, Share, c(3,4,6), -Code, -Fruit_Name) %>%
              arrange(Fruit_Name) %>%
              mutate_all(funs(str_replace(., "2018bis", "2018")))))
```

I would like to have a graph more or less like this

```
ggplot(x, aes(x = Year, y = Share, color = Fruit_Name)) + 
geom_line(size = 2) + 
facet_grid(Fruit_Name~ .)
```

which allows me to have a graph with Year on the x axis and Share on the y axis for each Fruit within each Code group.

**I have trouble specifying each nested dataframe for the ggplot!
I don't want to construct a dataframe from the list but try to access the existing ones.**

I have tried something like this:

```
myplot <- function(x){ggplot(x, aes(x = Year, y = Share, color = Fruit_Name)) + 
geom_line(size = 2) + 
facet_grid(Code~ .)}

i <- c(1,2,3)
for (x in i){
  lapply(fruits[["i"]], map_depth(x, 2, myplot(fruits2)))
}
```

but it doesn't work as in any case ggplot requires a dataframe as an argument and not a list!!

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. And your example seems to have undefined variables such as `Occupation` and `fruit_long`. And maybe `fruits[["i"]]` should be `fruits[[i]]`. But ggplot will only take data.frames; it will not take lists of lists. You can't change that. You need to make sure you pass in a data.frame for plotting.

Comment: If you run the code you will see that the list fruits contains 3 nested lists, each of which contains 3 data frames (fruit_normal, fruit_long, fruit2). I would like to plot Year, Share for BOTH fruit_long and fruit_2 for each of the sublists. Therefore the argument that I am passing to ggplot are 2 dataframes, i just don't know how to access them as they are in a list within a list and I also don't know how to loop through them as I want the same graph for each sublist. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a typo in your example data since you don't rename Share_2010 like the others, so I started with

```
fruits <- df %>%
  rename("2002" = Share_2002,
         "2010" = Share_2010,
         "2018" = Share_2018,
         "2018bis" = Share_2018_bis) %>%
  arrange(Code)%>%
  group_split(Code) %>%
  map(~list(fruit_normal = .x, fruit_long = .x %>%
                            gather(Year, Share, c(3,4,5), -Code, -Fruit_Name) %>%
                            arrange(Fruit_Name) %>%
                            mutate_all(funs(str_replace(., "2018bis", "2018"))),
            fruits2 = .x %>%
              gather(Year, Share, c(3,4,6), -Code, -Fruit_Name) %>%
              arrange(Fruit_Name) %>%
              mutate_all(funs(str_replace(., "2018bis", "2018")))))
```

Then added a grouping aesthetic to your plotting code and made it a function

```
plotFruit <- function(df) {
    ggplot(df, aes(group = Fruit_Name, x = Year, y = Share, color = Fruit_Name)) + 
        geom_line(size = 2) + 
        facet_grid(Fruit_Name~ .)}
```

And unpacked this bulky data structure using

```
map(fruits, pluck, "fruit_long") %>% map(plotFruit)
```

and

```
map(fruits, pluck, "fruits2") %>% map(plotFruit)
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: This is very useful! What if I wanted both plots on the same graph to see the divergence between 2018 and 2018bis? I have modified the function to include 2 dataframes but I am not sure how to pass them with map and pluck!

Comment: map2 would probably be a good idea to pass x and y and the function plotFruit but how do I pass them with pluck? thank you